# How to use ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have the following data that I want to use ng-repeat on:

```
{"data":[{"id":1,"namn":"Bryan","efternamn":"Karlsson"},{"id":2,"namn":"Kalle","efternamn":"Kula"},{"id":3,"namn":"Fisk","efternamn":"Fisksson"},{"id":4,"namn":"Daniel","efternamn":"Fisksson"}]}
```

Im trying to use it like this:

```
<div ng-controller="Test">
<tr ng-repeat="namn in test">
    <td>{{namn}}</td>
</tr>
</div>
```

I have no idea why. Is it because of the "data" in the JSON-string?

Here is my controller:

```
as.controller('Test', function($scope, $http, $rootScope)
{   
    $http.get($rootScope.appUrl + '/nao/test/test')
        .success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
            $scope.test = data;
    });
});
```

Comment: You have no idea why what?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<div ng-controller="Test">
  <tr ng-repeat="record in test.data">
    <td>{{record.namn}}</td>
  </tr>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<div ng-controller="Test">
<tr ng-repeat="namn in test.data">
    <td>{{namn}}</td>
</tr>
</div>
```